# Restore Kubuntu on a hosed system

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery

My Dell Inspiron 16 is totally hosed. This machine has peculiar bootup behavior in any case, since there's no way to simply boot from a CD or memory stick that doesn't depend on the installed operating system. In its current state the system gives me a Grub prompt no matter how I start it. I can then boot from USB or a CD (it says). I have both Windows and Ubuntu installed (but now inaccessible) as a result of some misadventures with Boot Repair. I also have various systems on  memory sticks, but none of them will start either Ubuntu or Windows. I do have a memory stick with SuperGrub which enables me to access various images but none of them work.

I suppose that what would get me going would be a memory stick that will boot Windows (unlikely) or some form of Linux.  But almost everything I try takes me back to that Grub prompt or that devilish  Windows boot-repair loop. If I could find a Linux system that would start up, that could be way in.  Even then I would have a long road to a working system, probably via a Dell factory image restore. I also have SuperGrub, which will take me to the installed systems, but not to a starting point that works.

Any hints or suggestions?  I do have an HP laptop running Kubuntu and Windows, but it's infuriatingly slow.

Comment: You can try booting it from the grub prompt using this procedure https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/ if your pc is uefi the last part - to fix it - won't work, but if it's bootable this should boot it.

Comment: Seems like we need to know more about the "*peculiar bootup behavior*." Is this some kind of security you built? Or it is a set of BIOS settings you chose? Or is this some kind of Super Duper Secure Boot run amok? Or is this something baked into the BIOS that you cannot disable? (If so, how did you install Ubuntu?)